# Relocate the table index in python 3

Tags: python, tkinter, indexing, grid, label

Query = search _entry.get()

Sql = *SELECT FROM customers where last_name = %s"

Data = (query,)

Result = my_cursor. Execute (sql, data)

Result = my_cursor. fetchall ()

If not result :

Result = "record not found... "

Query_label = Label(search _customer _window, text =result)

Query_label. Place (x=40,y=130)

else :

For index, x in enumerate (result) :

Num =0

Index +=2

For y in x:

Query_label = Label(search _customer_window, text=y)

Query_label.grid(row=index,column=num)

Num +=1

I set the value of index to 2 but nothing happens. Thanks for your help.

When I run the program, the label (query_lqbel) is shown at top left side of the window (row 0, column =0), how can I change the location of label. Its actually a label on which some data are shown.

Comment: Please fix the formatting and typos of your code. It is better to provide a [mre].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: rows and columns without widget will have zero size.  That is why the table starts at the top-left corner of the window even though the table starts at row 2.  You can put the table in a `frame` and then use `frame.pack(padx=..., pady=...)` or `frame.place(x=..., y=...)` to put the frame at the position you want.